# I am facing an undefined reading length error in my code below

Tags: javascript, deployment, solidity, hardhat

This is the error I am getting when I try to deploy the code:

> Error: ERROR processing /home/anooj-patnaik/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/deploy/00-deploy-mocks.js:
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')**

```js
const { network } = require("hardhat")

const {

    developmentChains,

    DECIMALS,

    INITIAL_ANSWER,

} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {

    const { deploy, log } = deployments

    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {

        log("Local Network Detected! Deploying Mocks...")

        await deploy("MockV3Aggregator", {

            contract: "MockV3Aggregator",

            from: deployer,

            log: true, 

            args: [DECIMALS, INITIAL_ANSWER],

        })

        log("Mocks deployed")

        log("---------------------------")

    }

}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]
```

I have defined all the variables in a hardhat-helper-config.js and hardhat.config.js. The MockV3Aggregator is in a separate contract

Tried to deploy the code above and faced with an error

Comment: The given example doesn't contain `length` anywhere. The error message contais the file name, the exact line number and the exact column number to start with. Locate the error and translate the error message to your native language so that you can thoroughly understand what is going on in your code. Then if you'll still get stuck, ask a question.

Comment: @Teemu here for some explanation regarding that: https://trackjs.com/blog/debugging-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined/         I am unable to find what exactly is undefined here. The error message seems to be pointing towards the deploy function

Comment: Now look, you're looking at a wrong code, follow the error stack to locate the correct script and place which eventually fired the error. If it's a framework or library code, make sure you've passed everything correctly when calling a library method.

Answer (score 0):

When you call await `getNamedAccounts()`, it looks in your `hardhat.config.js` for the `namedAccounts` section, and reads the length of the named accounts.

You'll want to make sure this is in there!

```
namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 0, // here this will by default take the first account as deployer
        },
    },
```